# CSS Styles - Elements move towards centre when browser window is resized

Tags: html, css

Here I have a webpage. If I change the size of the browser window this happens: http://gyazo.com/1be5c2f9aae817d0fa2603a51bea5d37 and the smaller the browser window the closer the two banner elements get towards the centre.

I was wondering if anyone could help me stop these two elements from moving towards the centre when the browser window size is changed so that they're simular to the green and blue box on this site: https://woodycraft.net/home/

Here is my CSS Style sheet:

```
/*CSS FOR ALL PAGES*/

/*BODY/WRAPPER SECTION*/

body {background:url('E:/Documents/CRAFT412-Website/images/SiteBackground.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;}

#wrapper {width: 1000px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          background-color: white;
          border-radius: 5px;
          box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;}

/*TOP BANNER SECTION*/

#logo {margin-top: -90px;
       margin-bottom: -95px;
       text-align: center;}

#ip {float: left;
     margin-left: 458px;
     margin-top: -55px;}

#ip_text {float: left;
          margin-left: 449px;
          margin-top: -51px;
          color: white;
          font-size: 15px;}

#teamspeak_logo {float:right;
                 margin-right: 450px;
                 margin-top: -55px;}
```

Also here is the HTML for that said page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <title>CRAFT412 - Rules</title>
</head>

<!--PAGE LINKS-->

<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="css/rules.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">

<!--HTML FOR ALL PAGES-->

<!--BODY SECTION-->

<body>

    <!--TOP BANNER SECTION-->

    <div id="banner">

                   <div id="logo"> 
                                <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Logo.png" width="500" height="281" alt="CRAFT412">
                            </div>

                   <div id="ip">
                              <img class="top" src="images/CRAFT412 - Box - IP.png" alt="IP">
                           </div>

                   <div id="ip_text">
                                   <p>SERVER IP<P/>
                                   <p>craft412.serveminecraft.net<P/>
                               </div>

                   <div id="teamspeak_logo"> 
                                          <a href="ts3server://craft412.serveminecraft.net:9987">
                                          <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Box - Teamspeak.png" alt="TEAMSPEAK"></a>
                                      </div>                                       
                                  </div>

    <!--WRAPPER SECTION-->

    <div id="wrapper">

                    <!--TOP NAV BAR SECTION-->

                    <div id="nav_bar">
                                    <ul>
                                      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                                      </li
                                      ><li><a href="status.html">Status</a>
                                      </li
                                      ><li><a href="info.html">Info</a>
                                      </li
                                      ><li><a href="">Gamemodes</a> 
                                    <ul>
                                       <li><a href="survival.html">Survival</a>
                                       </li
                                       ><li><a href="pure-pvp.html">Pure-PVP</a>
                                       </li
                                       ><li><a href="gamesworld.html">Gamesworld</a>
                                       </li>
                                    </ul>
                                       </li
                                       ><li><a href="rules.html" class="active-page">Rules</a>
                                       </li
                                       ><li><a href="vote.html">Vote</a>
                                       </li
                                       ><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                                       </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                    <!--RULES CONTENT-->

                    <div id="rules_title">
                                        <h3>RULES</h3>
                                    </div>

                    <div id="global_rules_info">
                                              <h3>GLOBAL RULES</h3>

                                              <p>Global rules follow across the entire server</p>

                                              <p>All players are expected to comply to all of the listed rules or they will be muted, kicked, timed out or banned</p>                                       
                                          </div>

                    <div id="global_rules">             
                                         <h4>Rule listing:</h4>

                                         <ul>
                                           <li>No griefing</li>
                                           <li>No flying. (Unless you've been given a high enough rank)</li>
                                           <li>No unauthorized mod usage</li>
                                           <li>No hacked clients</li>
                                           <li>No cheating</li>
                                           <li>Show all other players respect. Including staff</li>
                                           <li>No begging for rank</li>
                                        </ul> 

                                         <p>All rules are enforced by staff in a strict manner</p>
                                     </div>                                          

                    <div id="punishments">                     
                                        <h4>Punishments can include:</h4> 

                                        <ul>
                                          <li>Privilages taken away</li>
                                          <li>Mutes</li>
                                          <li>Prison (Survival)</li>
                                          <li>Temporary bans</li>
                                          <li>Permanent bans</li>
                                          <li>IP bans</li>
                                       </ul>
                                   </div>

                    <div id="survival_rules_title">                                                                                                                          
                                                <h3>SURVIVAL RULES</h3>
                                             </div>

                    <div id="survival_rules"> 
                                           <h4>Rule listing:</h4>

                                           <ul>
                                             <li>Global rules</li>
                                             <li>Don't build to close to other peoples creations, keep a reasonable distance</li>
                                             <li>No begging for materials</li>
                                          </ul>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                    <!--HTML FOR ALL PAGES-->

                    <!--BOTTOM FOOTER SECTION-->

                    <div id="bottom_footer">                    
                                          <div id="created_by">
                                                             <p>© 2015 GR412</p>
                                                         </div>

                                          <div id="social_media_youtube"> 
                                                                       <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/GR412" target="_blank">
                                                                       <img src="images/CRAFT412 - YouTube Button.png" width="40" height="40" alt="YOUTUBE"></a>
                                                                   </div>

                                          <div id="social_media_twitch"> 
                                                                      <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/gr412" target="_blank">
                                                                      <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Twitch Button.png" width="35" height="35" alt="TWITCH"></a>
                                                                  </div>

                                          <div id="social_media_twitter"> 
                                                                       <a href="https://twitter.com/GR412" target="_blank">
                                                                       <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Twitter Button.png" width="55" height="55" alt="TWITTER"></a>
                                                                   </div>

                                          <div id="social_media_facebook"> 
                                                                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/GR412" target="_blank">
                                                                        <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Facebook Button.png" width="45" height="40" alt="FACEBOOOK"></a>
                                                                    </div>                                                                

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML of the banners and you shouldn't use E:/Documents/CRAFT412-Website/images/SiteBackground.png' but /images/SiteBackground.png'

Comment: Not sure what you mean, also I haven't got it hosted yet so this is expression webs viewer.

Comment: Pretty hard to debug without your HTML markup. Also, you only need to give us the relevant CSS for those elements, not your entire stylesheet.

Comment: Hard to say without the option to look at it live. But i would guess it's something with the margin-left on #ip  and margin-right on #teamspeak_logo. Have you used the Inspector in Chrome and looked at it when it's not working?

Comment: I've put the HTML there can't you see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you would like to keep the buttons from moving towards the center?

```
#ip_text {float: left;
      margin-left: 449px; // Try remove this
      margin-top: -51px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 15px;
}

#teamspeak_logo {float:right;
      margin-right: 450px; // Try remove this
      margin-top: -55px;
}
```

Comment: That fixes it however they're now in the wrong positions. Is there a way I can put them back to their original positions instead of using margins.